# facebook graphql story_fbid

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to retrieve a post's id from the URL I can get. The format is as below:
https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=pfbid0KG7oNvji6Vkj924pvCDhw9pDjGZVArrXsRdtVTS2FVumGR126VLc8CxWQ9oAkz15l&id=101398992546060

Previously it was working when the story_fbid is something similar to the pageId itself; however, the story_fbid format seems to have changed, and I can't find any API I could look into.

The post_id, as well as the permanent_url, wasn't matching the URL I had.
I needed the post_id to match the webhook sent from Facebook to trigger my work. Any help would be appreciated.